# How to use Windows built-in Find user, contacts and groups tool in .Net

Tags: c#, active-directory

I intend to create a manifest of Windows users and I need to hand-pick them from the valid users on an unknown computer.

There are lots of different types of environments:

- single computer with local users only
- domain computer with local and domain users
- domain computer with local users and users from the various domains of the forest

So I don't want to implement a custom solution to handle all the various types and also there is a built-in solution in Windows:

[image]

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any code to access the *Find users…* dialog, but I guess, in the last 20 years someone has created a NuGet for that so there must be some code to rely on.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the [Directory Object Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/directory-object-picker) dialog.

Someone made a package that wraps the native calls for .NET: [Active-Directory-Object-Picker](https://github.com/Tulpep/Active-Directory-Object-Picker)

You can install it from NuGet: [Tulpep.ActiveDirectoryObjectPicker](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tulpep.ActiveDirectoryObjectPicker/)

There is example code on the GitHub page:

```cs
DirectoryObjectPickerDialog picker = new DirectoryObjectPickerDialog()
{
    AllowedObjectTypes = ObjectTypes.Computers,
    DefaultObjectTypes = ObjectTypes.Computers,
    AllowedLocations = Locations.All,
    DefaultLocations = Locations.JoinedDomain,
    MultiSelect = true,
    ShowAdvancedView = true
};


if (picker.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    foreach (var sel in picker.SelectedObjects)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sel.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, exactly what I was looking for. Found it, too ;)